# PHP PDO update prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to update my database with the following query:

```
$sth = "UPDATE rpacks SET rpacks_location VALUES (:location) WHERE rpacks_id = (:id)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sth);
$q->execute(array(':location'=>$location, ':id'=>$id));
```

**But I'm getting this error**

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax     error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('test') WHERE rpacks_id = ('2')' at line 1' in`

Comment: Your SQL statement has an error you should use SET field = (:Something) not values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a mistake in your `update` query because you used `insert` query syntax.

Here is the correct query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rpacks SET rpacks_location = :location WHERE rpacks_id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([':location'=>$location, ':id'=>$id]);
```

**Reference:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

`$sth = "UPDATE rpacks SET rpacks_location = :location WHERE rpacks_id = :id";`